# How to plot a tuple with character

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tuples

I have 2 tuple like below:

```
L1 = [(10955, 'A'), (10954, 'A'), (10953, 'A'), (10952, 'AB'), (10951, 'AB'), (10950, 'AB'), (10949, 'AB'), (10948, 'ABC')]

L2 = [(10956, 'AB'), (10955, 'AB'), (10954, 'A'), (10953, 'ABC'), (10952, 'DEF'), (10951, 'ABC'), (10950, 'AB'), (10949, 'ABC'), (10948, 'ABC'), (10947, 'ABCD')]
```

I want plot them in matpltlib as below:

```
10956 |     | AB
10955 | A   | AB
10954 | A   | A
10953 | A   | ABC
10952 | AB  | DEF
10951 | AB  | ABC
10950 | AB  | AB
10949 | AB  | ABC
10948 | ABC | ABC
10947 | ABCD| 
-------------------
      | L1  | L2
```

How to plot char fileds in matplotlib.

Comment: What have you tried that did not work or gave unexpected results?

Comment: "How to plot char fileds in matplotlib.". This is a very broad statement. What is the desired plot? How should it look like? You are showing a table.

Comment: I want my output as per the table. Vertical and Horizontal lines can be considered as grids.

Comment: `plt.table()`? Is the problem to get the header below the table?

Comment: So you just want a particularly styled console output? You want to merge `L1` and `L2` together on the numeric value, and make a columnar table? You don't need matplotlib for that, right?

Comment: Yes thats right - Jordan Singer

Comment: Console output is something other than matplotlib. Can you be clear on what **exactly** you are trying to achieve and what hinders you in that?

Comment: No Sir, I am new to python. I am even ok with console output. As plotting values with line ot dot is Ok. But unable to handle characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may suggest to look into `pandas`. You can get a nice table out of your data by creating two separate dataframes first and then concatenate them on the same index.

```
import pandas as pd

L1 = [(10955, 'A'), (10954, 'A'), (10953, 'A'), (10952, 'AB'), 
      (10951, 'AB'), (10950, 'AB'), (10949, 'AB'), (10948, 'ABC')]
L2 = [(10956, 'AB'), (10955, 'AB'), (10954, 'A'), (10953, 'ABC'), 
      (10952, 'DEF'), (10951, 'ABC'), (10950, 'AB'), (10949, 'ABC'), 
      (10948, 'ABC'), (10947, 'ABCD')]

s1 = pd.DataFrame(L1, columns=["index", "L1"]).set_index("index")
s2 = pd.DataFrame(L2, columns=["index", "L2"]).set_index("index")

df = pd.concat((s1, s2), join="outer", axis=1).fillna("")

print(df)
```

This will result in

```
        L1    L2
index
10947       ABCD
10948  ABC   ABC
10949   AB   ABC
10950   AB    AB
10951   AB   ABC
10952   AB   DEF
10953    A   ABC
10954    A     A
10955    A    AB
10956         AB
```

in the console.

You could then also save the table to html and open it in a webbrowser

```
df.to_html('out.html')
import webbrowser, os
webbrowser.open('file://' + os.path.realpath("out.html"))
```

[image]

If using jupyter, the standard output of pandas dataframe looks very nice by itself.

[image]

Using matplotlib (because the question asks for it) one can plot the values from a dataframe inside of an axes, like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for ind, data in np.ndenumerate(df.values):
    ax.annotate(data, xy=ind[::-1])

ax.set(xticks=range(len(df.columns)), yticks =range(len(df)),
       xticklabels=df.columns, yticklabels=df.index)
ax.set(xlim=(-1, len(df.columns)+1),
       ylim=(-1, len(df)), 
       aspect=.6)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Also, matplotlib provides tables

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.table(cellText=df.values, rowLabels=df.index, colLabels=df.columns, loc='center')
ax.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sir, Your code with matplotlib was very Helpful. Need one more help. I want to plot the copy Y-xis in other side too.